# FFmpeg/avconv and UDP - connect listener after sender?

Tags: ffmpeg, port, udp

I'm trying to troubleshoot a port binding issue in avconv/FFmpeg. I have two test commands; one which sends an audio stream over UDP:

```
avconv -i test.wav "udp://localhost:6613?localport=6614&reuse=1&connect=0"
```

And one that listens for it:

```
avconv -loglevel debug -f wav -ac 1 -i "udp://localhost:6613?reuse=1&connect=0" out.wav
```

If the second (listener) command is run before the first, it works; it simply hangs there until the first begins sending data across that port.

However, if the first command is started *first*, and begins sending data before the listener is set up, running the second command produces the following output:

```
Opening an input file: udp://localhost:6613.  
udp://localhost:6613: Operation not permitted
```

However, **this is not a port binding error**!

If I remove `reuse=1` from the second command and run it twice - thereby actually trying to bind the socket twice - it generates the following message:

```
Opening an input file: udp://localhost:6613.
[udp @ 0x1a77140] bind failed: Address already in use
udp://localhost:6613: Input/output error
```

As long as `reuse=1` is still in the command, running it twice will *not* raise an error from binding, and it's in the test commands in hopes that it would solve the problem... which it doesn't.

So, I would like to know why it has a problem listening to an ongoing stream - and, moreover, how to prevent that.